# Can't get <= to operate properly on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Beginner. I am trying to have a program shut down when the input is <= 0, and thus far I have been unable to get the file to save due to invalid syntax.

What I have right now is

```
print("Enter in a miles per gallon figure: ")

mpg = (int(input("MPG: ")

if mpg <= 0:
       exit()
```

When I attempt to save this to run it, I get invalid syntax highlighting the colon after 0. I have tried spacing the colon and 0 differently and I have been unsuccessful so far. I tried adding a second colon with no success. I have tried a number of other things I thought might work, I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: `mpg = (int(input("MPG: ")` has unmatched parentheses. Write `mpg = int(input("MPG: "))` instead.

Comment: Please don't add things like 'SOLVED' to your question, instead accept the answer that you think is best or helped you most.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the close parenthesis:

```
mpg = int(input("MPG: "))
```

Comment: When the problem in the question is *caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced*, you should vote to close, instead of writing an answer: *While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.*

Comment: Appreciate the help there, but unfortunately, it still returned invalid syntax on the colon.
EDIT: nvm I screwed up, figured it out, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
mpg = (int(input("MPG: ")
```

should be

```
mpg = int(input("MPG: "))
```

Moreover, why using 2 commands

```
print("Enter in a miles per gallon figure: ")

mpg = int(input("MPG: "))
```

if you may use only the second, slightly modified?

```
mpg = int(input("Enter in a miles per gallon figure (MPG): ")
```